# Get a string out of an array\object in yahoo pipes?

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I have a pipe which is attempting to extract a youtube id from a youtube channel feed.

I have:

Fetch Feed -> Sub Element (item.link) -> Truncate (After 1) -> Regex (blah) -> Output

My problem is the output is:

```
0
   content ABGmhMBBGgw
```

I can't seem to put this output into a string builder because it's an object (maybe array?).

So how can I extract the raw string out of this object array thing I have now.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can use the pipe module called "create RSS" and make it's tittle from regexp result.

It will contain desired string as title instead of given 0, but will be an array anyway.

Answer (score -1):

A demo showing how to extract latest video from a Youtube channel and embed into a webpage, all done with javascript and a Yahoo Pipe can be found at...  http://lovelogic.net/z_tuts/ytgrab3.html

Just right click to view the page source and learn how the JSON from the yahoo pipe is decoded then swapped into the HTML, details of the pipe itself can be found here http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=19431b877cc39a2d5fe8efa00bd86009

Comment: -1 This doesn't answer the question, which was about extracting the ID and using it in a string builder.